# AngularJs Routing | don't change URL

Tags: url, redirect, refresh, router, angular-ui-router

I am developing an App that uses the AngularJs Router.

So my URLs look  like that:

```
appName/viewOrders
```

My problem is, when I refresh the browser with F5 I get an 404 Error. (Because there isn't a folder or even file named viewOrders)

I can't redirect it via a config file because I am not able to use one in the environment where I am developing (An Sharepoint 2013 App).

So I came to this idea:
When I click the navigation, the Url doesn't change and stays at

```
/appName
```

But the view does it.
How can I achieve it? Have I to use the ui-router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have restricted access and are unable to use the answer @tommyd456 (which it sounds like that may be the case), another option is to omit the url completely using stateProvider (ui-router).

[Angular ui-router: Can you change state without changing URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791071/angular-ui-router-can-you-change-state-without-changing-url)

Comment: I have already found a solution that works for me at the moment (did it with ng-include). But thanks a lot for the link, that is for what I were searching :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've solved this issue but here's a potential solution anyway...

You're using HTML5 mode so you need server-side rewrite as explained here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

However, it sounds like you've got restricted access to a server so why stop HTML5 mode.

Don't hack at it like you're suggesting - that could get nasty.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already a solution for it (did it with ng-include at the moment).
I am working on a Sharepoint hosted App and am not allowed to do a server side rewrite via a config file or anything else. That is the problem, why I were searching for such a (nasty) solution.