# angular-ui-router: States without URL but with working back navigation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In angular-ui-router, the states don't need to have an URL. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791071/angular-ui-router-can-you-change-state-without-changing-url).

This works fine when clicking through the UI, however, it seems that back navigation is broken that way:

http://plnkr.co/edit/kr7hyjc1q8i15vcSG9RR?p=preview

```js
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false,
  }).hashPrefix('!');

  $stateProvider.state({ 
    name: 'home', 
    controller: function($scope) { }, 
    template: '<h1>home state loaded</h1> ' +
                 '<div ui-view></div>'
  });

  $stateProvider.state({ 
    name: 'home.foo', 
    controller: function() { }, 
    template: '<h1>foo state loaded</h1> ' +
              '<div ui-view></div>'
  });
});
```

Do some state transitions, then right-click in the window and choose "back" in the context menu. Instead of going back one state, the frame becomes blank.

Is there a way to have states without associated URLs, but with working pushState / history?