# dynamic view loading in custom directives' widget in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, uiview, widget

I am using custom Directive's approach in AngularJS for making dashboard with widgets and for widgets m using angular-gridster
(https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster).

**Requirements:**

[image]

On right side menu created by custom directive is present.and for routing purpose UI Router in used.

1-I need to open a dashboard firstly empty.

2-when click to Menu1 one widget is opened with data from state menu1 and same for Menu2

3-when 2nd option is clicked another widget added to dashboard without affecting previously opened one and so on.

4-all the widgets have independent data.and navigation in each widget is according to the respective menu.

**WorkFlow:**

1-empty dashboard is opened via custom directive.

2-widgets are added by providing click event to menu1 and menu2.which will broadcast event.and against that click event a widget is added to widgets array holding information about that widget.

**Problem:**

problem is routing basically.till now there is no routing involved.info is passed by broadcasting a click event.and by this i have achieved this coloured area.[image]

but the further navigation creates problem.when a state changes by clicking Menu1 or Menu2 it affects both the widgets and and ui-view portion in both widgets show same data.if Menu1 is clicked both widgets show data from Menu1 and vice versa.

Now.i have tried enough solutions but here i want an idea from ui router experts or custom directives' experts.cz i hv tried many possible ways and stuck here for almost a week.

Thanx very very much if anyone can help.

Comment: Just a thought, Menu1 and Menu2 changing together suggests a shared scope with their mutual parent.  Have you checked scope inheritance?

Comment: menu1 and menu2 inherited from same parent which is main menu.but the child of these two menu1 and menu2 should be of different scope which couldn't be achieved.

Comment: Perhaps I don't have an accurate concept of the structure.  But if the child for each, menu1 and menu2, was a custom directive then each could have an isolate scope and their navigation could be managed independently.

Comment: no child are not custom directives.they are simply partials loaded through state change.

Comment: Right, those views are scoped to the same controller.  I don't use ui.router, but still wondering if the $state template could point to a directive with its own controller allowing you to have different data for each 'view'.  I'm thinking about something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790209/angular-ui-router-ui-views-vs-directives

Comment: $state isn't pointing to a directive directly but by state->template.e.g;$state.go("home");$stateProvider.state("home",{url:"some-url-here",template:"<custom-directive></custom-directive>"});this navigation isn't as tough problem is navigation between states inside <cusom-directive></custom-direcive>.